# Дана последовательность ненулевых чисел после которой следует 0. Рекурсия

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Такая задачка: Дана последовательность ненулевых чисел, за которой следует 0. Напечатать сначала все отрицательные , а затем все положительные числа этой последовательности(в любом порядке).
ВАЖНО! Сделать, чтобы код это делал через рекурсивный алгоритм.

В общем и целом я не знаю как правильно задать параметры функции. Чтобы именно эти блоки работали верно

```
        int[] row = { -2, 3, 5, 2, -3, 0 };
        bool bPositive = false;
        static int Recursion(....)
        {
           
            if (row[i])
            {
                if (bPositive && row[i] < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(row[i] + " ");
                }
                if (!bPositive && row[i] > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(row[i] + " ");
                }
                Recursion(i + 1, bPositive);
            }
        }
        static int Recursion(....)
        {
            Recursion(row, 0, true);
            Recursion(row, 0, false);
            return 0
        }
```

Comment: а где вопрос? .

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: @aepot Извините недавно начал пользоваться сайтом. Только , как поступил начал изучать сишарп. Приношу извинения за кривой код

Comment: @timur исправил

Comment: @TheDesireToBelieve кривой код в вопросе - это нормально, если что. А вот в если ответе - то не очень. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

по идее алгоритм мог бы быть простым:

пройтись по последовательности до 0 2 раза - первый раз выводить только отрицательные числа, второй - только положительные

но в этом случае не будет рекурсии

в качестве рекурсионного алгоритма можно сделать функцию, которая на вход принимает массив, и позицию в массиве

внутри функция `show_negative` выбирает значение `arr[pos]`, выводит его для отрицательных чисел и вызывает себя, но с новой позицией `show_negative(arr, pos + 1)`

если нашла значение 0 - то просто функция прекращает выполнение

тоже самое для положительных чисел - функция `show_positive`

вот это уже рекурсионный алгоритм

По идее можно совместить обе функции (для отрицательных и положительных чисел в одну) - будем считать, что пока мы идем слева направо, то выводим только отрицательные, а справа налево - положительные

тогда функция будет содержать еще и 3 параметр - `isNegative` который может быть `true` или `false`

если `isNegative == true` делаем все как функция `show_negative`, при достижении 0 меняем `isNegative = false` и делаем все как функция `show_positive`, при достижении позиции `-1` прекращаем выполнять функцию

в результате будет сначала выведен список отрицательных чисел, потом положительных

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: только я все равно не понимаю какие параметры должны быть заданы у функции

Comment: если выбрать последний описанной вариант - одна функция для всей задачи, то она должна принять 3 параметра - массив значений, позицию в массиве значений, направление движения - `show(arr, position, direction)`, если `direction == true`, то идем направо и вызываем рекурсивно `show(arr, position + 1, direction)`, если `direction == false` идем налево и вызываем рекурсивно `show(arr, position - 1, direction)`, если в ячейке `arr[pos] == 0`, то меняем направление движения - `direction = false`, если достигли начала массива `position == -1`, то просто прекращаем выполнять функцию

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, всё гораздо проще же.
Отрицательные выводим сразу, положительные - после погружения в стек.

Вместо псевдокода напишу на js:

```js
function foo(a) {
  if (a.length === 0) return;

  const num = a[0];

  if (num === 0) return;
  if (num  < 0)  console.log(num);
  foo(a.slice(1))
  if (num  > 0) console.log(num);
}

const a = [-2, 3, 5, 2, -3, 0];

foo(a);
```

Comment: только положительные в обратном порядке

Comment: А в задании так и написано) В любом порядке

Comment: а теперь давай еще и в правильном :-D

Comment: таки сделал пример :-D https://jsfiddle.net/1vkcmega/

Answer (score 1):

Переписал код с советов:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] mass = new int[] { 12, -2, -3, 5, 6, 12, 0 };
            print(mass);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void print(int[] mass, int i = 0)
        {
            int num = mass[i];
            if (num == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (num < 0)
                Console.Write(num + " ");
            print(mass, ++i);
            if (num > 0)
                Console.Write(num + " ");
        }
```